# Map interface keys to an array of key value pairs

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given some interface

E.g.

```js
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number ;
}
```

I want to create a generic function that accepts the following arguments

```js
const res = Result.combineValues<Person>(
    { age: 18 },
    { name: 'John Doe' }
);
```

So far I have

```js
class Result<T> {

    readonly value: T;

    private constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static combineValues<T>(...results: { [key in keyof T]?: Result<T[key]> | T[key] }[]): Result<T> {
        let value: T;
        // ... compute value
        return new Result<T>(value);
    }
}
```

but the issue is that it allows for undefined values

```js
const res = Result.combineValues<Person>(
    { age: undefined }, // this should give a compile error because age should be a number or Result<number>
    { name: 'John Doe' }
);
```

and it does not validate that all the properties were defined

```js
const res = Result.combineValues<Person>(
    { age: 18 } 
    // should give a compile error because `{name: 'Some Name'}` is missing from argument list
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't have any method for breaking down a union or intersection type into its constituents, or specifying that a number of unknown types must "add up" to a known type.

For this reason, making the function generic on the *Result* type and trying to enforce a condition on the variadic argument tuple isn't going to work.

Instead: we make the function generic on the tuple of types it is passed, and infer the return type of the function based on the intersection of all those types. Then, you can enforce compile-time constraints by assigning the return value of the function to a variable of type `Result<Person>`, which will make sure the assignment is valid.

To allow for instances of the `Result` class, we also specify a type to replace all members of a type that are `Result<T> with T`.

```
type ReplaceResultsIn<Obj> = {
  [Key in keyof Obj]: Obj[Key] extends Result<infer T> ? T : Obj[Key]
}
type Combine<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] ? (ReplaceResultsIn<First>) & Combine<Rest> : unknown
```

We then type the `combineValues` function to return `Combine< the argument types >`:

```
class Result<T> {
  readonly value: T;

  public constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public static combineValues<T extends object[]>(...args: T): Result<Combine<T>> {
        let value!: Combine<T>;
        // ... compute value
        return new Result<Combine<T>>(value);
    }
}
```

Consumers of this class can now exist with type-safety:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

// these are all OK
const person: Result<Person> = Result.combineValues({age: new Result(21)}, {name: ""});
const person2: Result<Person> = Result.combineValues({age: 21, name: ""});
const person3: Result<Person> = Result.combineValues({age: 21}, {name: ""});
const person4: Result<Person> = Result.combineValues({name: new Result("")}, {age: new Result(21)});

// these are all bad
const person5: Result<Person> = Result.combineValues({});
const person6: Result<Person> = Result.combineValues({age: 21});
const person7: Result<Person> = Result.combineValues({name: 21}, {age: 21});
const thing = Result.combineValues("");
const thing2 = Result.combineValues(null);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=43&pln=20&pc=1#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-bE8nGejYgBe3aUoq-aDqm95TnOLBPiua4bu+267icAAsf5Nl+raoueXZiteRgDghMD2u2+DNKus7zneZEjhR47TrOG55nqcJFjAJZcWWMCUEcm6oThACsWHOgBuFMPhl49hBA6voJn4tgAbGJx44UBTqgYRclQeC04KShSl7gA7GpEmaR2BFXrppEGbR0EwAZyHVgWiZ4cB2k2X2VHLi5H5ucQPITh5WnWbJPnpmWXpAA)

Comment: I have tested your solution and it is what I needed in terms of type-safety, but it has one downside in the fact that IDE intellisense/autocomplete is not able to suggest which properties are available in Result.combineValues(...). It also also worths  mentioning, for anybody that might use this solution, that I had to update the typescript version from 3.9.7 to 4.4.2

Comment: If correctly configured, your IDE should be able to infer the return type fine... which IDE are you using? If VSCode, you should also select the typescript version used for the language server to be the same as your workspace.

Comment: i use Webstorm, and I belive it is configured correctly. But you can see this issue also in the Playground link you have provided.

Comment: Where are you getting this issue in the playground? If I type `Result.combineValues({age: new Result(21)}, {name: ""}).value.` the trailing period brings up intellisense with the two expected properties: `age (number)` and `name (string)`.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYmph.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X9Mp.png) are some examples from playground.

Comment: Indeed, it will be impossible to suggest the properties in this position because those properties determine the return type, and not the other way around. This is due to the above limitation in TS and I don't think there is any solution that gets around it.